What is the moment of inertia $I$ when angular velocity $ω$ is zero?
$$I = \dfrac{L}{\omega}$$
What is the moment of inertia when $\omega = 0$? Is it just not defined or is the formula not valid when $\omega = 0$?

Your equation does not Give Any information About $I$ because when $\omega=0$, $L=0$ too, Hence gives a undefined form. Or I may say, The equation is not mathematically valid for $\omega=0$, Instead what is valid will be $L=I \omega$

This is reading the formula in the wrong way. A better way is
$$L = I \omega. \tag{1}$$
The moment of inertia is a constant that depends only on the mass distribution of the body (in more generality, it is a tensor, but we don't need to dive into these details here). Hence, it is a property of the body, not of the movement. It turns out that the moment of inertia is precisely what relates the angular velocity $\omega$ to the angular momentum $L$. Notice how Eq. (1) is similar to
$$p = m v.$$
This is because the moment of inertia is the rotational analogue of the mass. Hence, it is a property of the body, not of the movement. The mass is not undefined when the velocity is zero. Rather, it just means that when the velocity is zero, so is the linear momentum.
There are lists of moments of inertia for many different solids. Wikipedia has one. The moment of inertia for a solid sphere of mass $m$ and radius $r$ with constant mass density, for example, is
$$I = \frac{2}{5} m r^2.$$
Notice this is a constant that depends only on the mass of the object (more specifically, on the mass distribution inside the object) and on the geometry of the object. There is no dependence on angular velocity or angular momentum, just like the mass does not depend on velocity or momentum.

$L=0$ when $\omega=0$. The equation is invalid at that point.
$I$ is like $m$. The equation is like $m = p/v$. Mass does not change when $v=0$, even though the equation doesn't work at that point.

The moment of inertia $I$ is a physical property of an object related to its resistance to angular acceleration and a change in angular momentum. It is not "defined" by angular acceleration or angular momentum no more than the analogous physical property of mass $m$ is "defined" by translational acceleration or change in linear momentum.
The two properties are related to translational and angular acceleration by Newton's 2nd law per
$$a=\frac{F_{net}}{m}$$
$$\alpha=\frac{\tau_{neet}}{I}$$
and to translational and angular momentum, $p$ and $L$ per
$$p=mv$$
$$L=I\omega$$
Hope this helps.

First of all, usually it's meaningful to define angular velocity to describe the motion of a rigid body, whose most general motion can be written as a composition of translation (of a point) and rotation.
Then, the expression you wrote has some problems:

it's not the most general expression of the angular momentum;
mathematically, angular momentum is not represented with a scalar but with a (pseudo)vector.

Let's add some details about the definition of the angular momentum of a rigid body, starting from point masses and then increasing the "complexity" of the system.
Definition of angular momentum. Let's start with the definition of angular momentum for a point mass $m$, in motion with velocity $\mathbf{v}$, w.r.t. a pole $H$, i.e.
$$\mathbf{L}_{H} = (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_H) \times m \mathbf{v} \ .$$
Angular momentum is an additive quantity, so it's possible to seamlessly define the angular momentum for a system of points,
$$\mathbf{L}_{H} = \sum_i \mathbf{L}_{i,H} = \sum_i (\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_H) \times m_i \mathbf{v}_i \ .$$
For a rigid body, the following relation holds between the velocities of two material points of the rigid body
$$\mathbf{v}_P - \mathbf{v}_Q = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q) \ .$$
It's possible to use the latter relation between all the points $i$ and the center of mass $G$ (that is a material point of the rigid body),
$$\mathbf{L}_H = \sum_i (\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_H) \times m_i \left[\mathbf{v}_G + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_G) \right] \ ,$$
and writing $\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_H = \mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_G + \mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_H$, it's possible to recast the angular momentum of a rigid body as
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{L}_H & = \sum_i \left[(\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_G) + (\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_H) \right] \times m_i \left[\mathbf{v}_G + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_G) \right] = \\ 
& = \underbrace{\sum_i m_i (\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_G)}_{=\mathbf{0}} \times \mathbf{v}_G + (\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_H) \times \underbrace{\sum_i m_i}_{= m} \mathbf{v}_G + \\
 & - \sum_i (\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_G) \times (\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_G) \times \boldsymbol{\omega} +  (\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_H) \times \big[  \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \underbrace{\sum_i m_i (\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_G)}_{= \mathbf{0}} \big] = \\
& = (\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_H) \times \mathbf{Q} + \mathbb{I}_G \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega} \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
having exploited the definition of the center of mass $G$ to set equal to zero two terms, and introduced the definition of momentum $\mathbf{Q}$ and the tensor of inertia w.r.t. the center of mass, $\mathbb{I}_G$.
Now, it's time to compare the latter general expression of the angular momentum of a rigid body with your formula $L = I \omega$. Even if you don't fully understand the derivation and the most general formula, you can guess that the term $I \, \omega$ is somehow related with $\mathbb{I}_G \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega}$, while the another contribution $(\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_H) \times \mathbf{Q}$ does not contain the angular velocity of the rigid body.
